# Consultar com INNER JOIN e escolher a referência do loop

Tags: php, sql, loop

Galera, estou consultando duas tabelas com `INNER JOIN` assim:

```
if (! $db->Query("select * from cad_produto inner join cad_variacoes on cad_variacoes.id_produto = cad_produto.id")) 

$db->Kill(); 

while (! $db->EndOfSeek()) {  
  $row = $db->Row();

  $titulo = $row->titulo; //TABELA 1

  $valor = $row->valor; //TABELA 2
  $quantidade = $row->quantidade; //TABELA 2
  $id = $row->id_produto; //TABELA 2
}
```

**TABELA 1:**

```
 +----------------------------+
 |           PRODUTO          |
 +------------+---------------+
 | ID         | TITULO        |
 | 1          | arroz         |
 |            |               |
 |            |               |
 |            |               |
 +------------+---------------+
```

**TABELA 2:**

```
 +---------------------------+
 |         ATRIBUTO 1        |
 +------------+--------------+
 | ID_PRODUTO | VALOR        |
 | 1          | 10           |
 |            |              |
 |            |              |
 |            |              |
 +------------+--------------+

 +---------------------------+
 |         ATRIBUTO 2        |
 +------------+--------------+
 | ID_PRODUTO | QUANTIDADE   |
 | 1          | 5            |
 | 1          | 6            |
 |            |              |
 |            |              |
 +------------+--------------+
```

Eu preciso que na hora do *loop* apareça somente o *loop* 
**COMO REFERÊNCIA À QUANTIDADE DE LINHAS DA TABELA 1 E NÃO DA TABELA 2**, mas está acontecendo o contrário. Está vindo assim:

```
ID(dado da tabela 2)    TITULO    VALOR QUANTIDADE
1                       ARROZ      10       5

ID(dado da tabela 2)    TITULO    VALOR QUANTIDADE
1                       ARROZ      10       6
```

Eu preciso que venha somente 1 linha e com seus respectivos atributos.

> UPDATE

Era pra ficar assim, pegando um valor aleatório da tabela 2:

```
ID(dado da tabela 2)    TITULO    VALOR QUANTIDADE
1                       ARROZ      10       5
```

Não posso colocar LIMIT 1, pois quando houver dois produtos ficará assim:

```
ID(dado da tabela 2)    TITULO    VALOR QUANTIDADE
1                       ARROZ      10       5

ID(dado da tabela 2)    TITULO    VALOR QUANTIDADE
2                       FEIJAO     11       1
```

Comment: Coloca o título fora do `while`.

Comment: Mas quando houver duas linhas na tabela 1, terão dois produtos consultados, dois títulos, um em cada linha.

Comment: Ah entendi. Foi mal. Mas nesse caso você quer que apareça como ? Pode reproduzir no seu post ? É pra somar a quantidade ? Porquê só assim para aparecer em uma linha só. `sum(quantidade) ` e  `group by id`

Comment: @DiegoSouza, vou editar...veja a mudança da pergunta em baixo.

Comment: Está um pouco complicado entender sua lógica. Não pode por `LIMIT 1` se não acontece o que você mostrou aí. Você quer que apareça uma linha aleatória com um valor da tabela 2 de apenas 1 produto ?

Comment: Isso, mas por produto, resumindo o loop é com base na tabela 1 com os dados da tabela 2.

Comment: Você já tentou usar o LEFT JOIN ao invés do INNER JOIN?

Comment: já, Igor silva ...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta você "contar" os IDs da tabela que deseja, então vc pode fazer algo tipo assim:

```
SELECT cad_produto.*,cad_variacoes.*, count(DISTINCT cad_produto.id) qtd
FROM cad_produto
INNER JOIN cad_variacoes ON cad_variacoes.id_produto = cad_produto.id
```

Onde *count(DISTINCT cad_produto.id) qtd* vai contar o IDs únicos, mesmo que o *JOIN* faça ele repetir.